# Use :contain in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, syntax, syntax-error

I get what I want by doing this:

```
$('#stats_0 li:contains("Speed")').text();
```

However, I have to query for other characteristics than Speed, in the very same list I just got by id. So in order not to make jQuery going out for haunting in the whole DOM, I would like to cache the list and then apply the filter.

I tried:

```
var list = $('#stats_0');
var txt = $(list).('li:contains("Speed")').text();
```

but I am getting a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

How should I proceed? The [ref](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function('...').('...')` is not valid JavaScript syntax. The invocation operator (`()`) should be used after a function for calling the function. You are looking for the `find` method:

```
list.find('li:contains("Speed")').text();
```

Also note there is no need to pass a `list` to the jQuery constructor as `list` is already a jQuery object. If you pass a jQuery object to the jQuery constructor, jQuery doesn't complain and it returns the same object but doing this is unnecessary and doesn't make a lot of sense.

---

And another option that you can use in your case is caching the target `li` elements and using the `filter` method:

```
var $list = $('#stats_0 li');
var txt = $list.filter(':contains("Speed")');
```

Comment: OK that worked. But can you please help me understand why I hadn't to write `$(list)`? Because, somehow, that functionality was stored by my first line of code?